# R: Propensity Score Matching. Does matchit function work with categorical matching variables?

Tags: r, matching

I am working with the matchIt packages and Propensity Score Matching in R. I saw some examples. But I could not find some example working with matching variables being factor ou character. For examples, age groups.

```
head(mydata)
    People region sex age_group treatment
    1      1      1   3         0
    2      1      2   5         0
    3      2      2   2         1
    4      2      2   3         0
    5      3      1   3         1
    6      3      1   6         1
```

Where the first four variables are from factor or character types. Also, the levels sex are Men = 1 and Famale = 2.

The following line works with numeric matching variables( tot, mim and dis)- stw is the treatment variable-

```
m.out = matchit(stw ~ tot + min + dis,
data = mydata, method = "nearest",
ratio = 1)
```

source: http://pareonline.net/getvn.asp?v=19&n=18

I would like to know if matchit function works with categorical matching variables. If not, is there some appropriate package?

Comment: Can I use dicothomizing for the categorical variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will work but nearest neighbor method works best with continuous variables. Just be sure that you have declared your variables as factors first (i.e., convert them to dummy binary variables).

See Stuart EA (2010). 2010. Statistical Science 25(1):1-25
https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1280841730